# How To Optimize BackgroundWorker, Implemented Process Is Slow.

Tags: c#, performance, optimization, process, backgroundworker

I implemented 'CheckFileSize()' function to BackgroundWorker and a progress bar because the search task can take long.  Since adding the BackgroundWorker thread, application times seems to be much slower.. how can I optimize, or what am I doing wrong?

```
        private void UploadApp()
        {
            label4.Visible = true;
            label4.Text = ("Please wait...");

            // Assign BackgroundWorker1 to start check file size.
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        }


        // Check for invalid file size in 'AppID' folder.       
        private void CheckFileSize()
        {
            // Set application directory.
            string AppDirectory = ("Z:/Projects/" + AppID);

            // Set maximum file size in byte size (2GB).
            long fileSizeLimit = 2000000000;

            // Get IEnumerable (as in a list) on all files by recursively scanning directory.
            var fileList = Directory.EnumerateFiles(AppDirectory, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

            // Retrieve the size of files.
            long fileSize    = (from file in fileList let fileInfo = new FileInfo(file) select fileInfo.Length).Sum();

            // Exit application utility if maximum file size found.
            if (fileSize >= fileSizeLimit)
            {
                //MessageBox.Show("Project folder '" + AppID + "' contain file size greater than or equal 2GB.  Manual SCM upload required.");
                DialogResult MsgResult;
                MsgResult = MessageBox.Show("Project folder '" + AppID + "' contain file size greater than or equal 2GB.  Manual SCM upload required.",
                                            "Invalid File Size",
                                            MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                                            MessageBoxIcon.Error);                
                Environment.Exit(0);
            } 
          }


        // BackgroundWorker1 runs 'DoWork' in the background to check invalid file size.
        private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            // Set for loop to increment progress bar.
            for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
            {
                CheckFileSize();

                // Method to report the percentage complete.
                backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i);

                // Cancel BackgroundWorker1.
                if (backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending)
                {
                    break;
                }                
            }
        }


        // Update the progress bar control when the worker thread reports progress.
        private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        }


        // Enable START and EXIT button when work is done or thread is cancelled.
        private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            button1.Enabled = true;
            button2.Enabled = false;
            button3.Enabled = true;
        }                                 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling CheckFileSize in a loop and that is quite expensive.  You would be better off using a FileSystemWatcher that would inform you of any change to files. You could then keep track of each file size change and update the total accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is not how reporting progress from a `BackgroundWorker` works. What you are doing is:

1. Run the `CheckFileSize` method 100 times
2. After each run, increase progress by 1%.

As far as I can tell, all 100 runs of `CheckFileSize` do the same thing. The only way that result can change is if the contents of the directories change between runs. So, the question is - do you expect the files to change while the code is running?

If not, then you should only run `CheckFileSize` once. If you need to report progress percentage, you must do this inside the method:

```
var fileList = Directory.GetFiles(AppDirectory, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
int fileCounter = 0;

long fileSize = 0;

foreach (string file in fileList)
{
    fileSize += new FileInfo(file).Length;
    if (fileSize >= fileSizeLimit)
    {
        //display message box etc.
        break;
    }
    fileCounter++;
    backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(((double)fileCounter/fileList.Count)*100);
}
```

This also has another optimization - the loop ends when the limit is reached, so we don't have to look at the sizes of the rest of the files (your code always goes through all of them).

If the directory content can change, then I don't really see how you can display a progress bar and I would probably go with `FileSystemWatcher` as Tarik suggests.

Aside from that, I don't really like the usage of `Environment.Exit`. I believe it would be better to just stop the `BackgroundWorker`, set a result and deal with it in the `RunWorkerCompleted` handler.